# remove spaces from cells in matrix

Tags: perl, matrix, sed, awk, tr

I have a matrix(5800 rows and 350 columns) of numbers. Each cell is either

```
0 / 0
1 / 1
2 / 2
```

What is the fastest way to remove all spaces in each cell, to have:

```
0/0
1/1
2/2
```

Sed, R, anything that will do it fastest.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your input a bit more. A matrix? In what? Why not just say "I have a text file", if that is what you have?

Comment: You're getting a ton of solutions that are probably useless since you haven't provided enough info on your input file format or desired output. At least tell us what character(s) separate the cells in your matrix.

Comment: Yes, it is a text file, but I said matrix (comma separated) as it describes it more accurately doesn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going for efficiency, you should probably use coreutils tr for such a simple task:

```
tr -d ' ' < infile
```

I compared the posted answers against a 300K file, using GNU awk, GNU sed, perl v5.14.2 and GNU coreutils v8.13. The tests were each run 30 times, this is the average:

```
awk  - 1.52s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 1.529 total
sed  - 0.89s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.900 total
perl - 0.59s user 0.00s system 98% cpu 0.600 total
tr   - 0.02s user 0.00s system 90% cpu 0.020 total
```

All testes were run as above (`cmd < infile`) and with the output directed to /dev/null.

Comment: As I knew how to do it in R and sed, this answer wins as it shows which is fastest. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed "s/ \/ /\//g" input.txt
```

It means:

> Replace the string `" / "` (`/ \/ /`) by one slash (`/\/`) and do it globally (`/g`).

Comment: @choroba: much better! Thank you for your tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` alternative that does exactly the same thing:

```
awk '{gsub(" ",""); print}' input.txt > output.txt
```

**Explanations:**

- `awk '{...}'`: invoke awk, then for each line do the stuff enclosed by braces.
- `gsub(" ","");`: replace all space chars (single or multiple in a row) with the empty string.
- `print`: print the entire line
- `input.txt`: specifying your input file as argument to awk
- `> output.txt`: redirect output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

A perl solution could look like this:

```
perl -pwe 'tr/ //d' input.txt > output.txt
```

You can add the `-i` switch to do in-place edit.