# Removing the "" in the matrix in R in order to work with rows with non empty elements for a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a matrix called: `combination_mat` and it looks like this:

`combination_mat  <- read.csv("Data.csv")`

`combination_mat  <- as.matrix(na.omit(combination_mat))`

> combination_mat

```
    X1        X2        X3       X4      
1  "FF"      "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS" "STLFSI"  
2  "FF"      "WGS10YR" "STLFSI" ""      
3  "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS"  "STLFSI" ""      
4  "FF"      "WTB3MS"  "STLFSI" ""      
5  "FF"      "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS" ""      
6  "FF"      "WTB3MS"  ""       ""      
7  "FF"      "STLFSI"  ""       ""      
8  "WGS10YR" "STLFSI"  ""       ""      
9  "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS"  ""       ""      
10 "FF"      "WGS10YR" ""       ""      
11 "STLFSI"  "WTB3MS"  ""       ""      
12 "FF"      ""        ""       ""      
13 "WGS10YR" ""        ""       ""      
14 "WTB3MS"  ""        ""       ""      
15 "STLFSI"  ""        ""       ""
```

However, after using `lapply()` for looping each row, I end up with the list with elements and the emplty elements e.g. `""`.

The result that I am looking for looks like this:

> combination_mat

```
    X1        X2        X3       X4      
1  "FF"      "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS" "STLFSI"  
2  "FF"      "WGS10YR" "STLFSI"     
3  "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS"  "STLFSI"     
4  "FF"      "WTB3MS"  "STLFSI"    
5  "FF"      "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS"      
6  "FF"      "WTB3MS"      
7  "FF"      "STLFSI"      
8  "WGS10YR" "STLFSI"      
9  "WGS10YR" "WTB3MS"      
10 "FF"      "WGS10YR"      
11 "STLFSI"  "WTB3MS"      
12 "FF"      
13 "WGS10YR"     
14 "WTB3MS"     
15 "STLFSI"
```

Some links I searched: [remove spaces from cells in matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634494/remove-spaces-from-cells-in-matrix)
[R: data.frame rows to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563975/r-data-frame-rows-to-list)
[Remove all empty elements from string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309072/remove-all-empty-elements-from-string-array)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to fill as blank elements?  If you have `''` elements and want to change it to `NA`, `is.na(combination_mat) <- combination_mat==''`  It is not a clear question.

Comment: Example: `m = matrix(c("A","B","C",""),2,2)` Then do `apply(m,1,function(x) x[x!=""])`

Comment: Thank you @Frank beautiful. I will check your answer once you have "officially" answered the question. Best regards, user3553260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't keep the data as a matrix/ data.frame whilst removing the elements, as the columns of the matrix would have different lengths. There are a couple of ways of dealing with it.

**Method 1:** ([Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank)'s comment) You could convert the matrix to a list and remove all of the elements, then access the elements of the list as if they were columns of a matrix:

```
m = matrix(c("A","B","C",""),2,2) 
apply(m,1,function(x) x[x!=""])
```

**Method 2:** You could keep the matrix form of the result, but convert the `""` entries to `NA` and then filter them from later calculations.

```
m = matrix(c("A","B","C",""),2,2) 
m[m == ""] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks for posting it. I get the impression that the OP wants to iterate over rows, not simply hide the `""` by printing, @RHertel.

Comment: I agree, @Frank ; I just thought it might be worth adding this possibility as a comment.

Comment: @Frank You are absolutely right about my intentions on looping through the matrices rows list by list through `lapply()`. I will up comment your comments Frank and this answer for effort. I truly appreciate everybody's effort! However, the credit is due to Frank for answering the question correctly first. Take care all!

Comment: Under this logic @JCollerton I will do that! Under the circumstances, Mr. Frank had his chance to "answer" the question like you have done. Nonetheless, I will check your answer right as well mate. Take care! Cheers!!!